# How to access elements of boost::python::tuple in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, boost-python

I have a C++ code called from Python. I have list of tuples passed from python:

```
boost::python::list<boost::python::tuple>
```

How do I access the elements of `boost::python::tuple`?

Any example would be handy. From the documentation, I can't find the accessor methods.

Comment: there must be a mapping function, and the methods are not fully  documented. for a quick workaround try to build a custom wrapper (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296287/boost-python-error-when-passing-variable-by-reference-in-a-function/53078586#53078586) for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the `boost::python::extract<int>( )` method.

For example for a python tuple containing an integer and a string:

Python side:

```
t = (123, 'some string')
```

C++ side:

```
void work_with_tuple(boost::python::tuple t)
{
   if (boost::python::len(t) != 2) throw std::invalid_argument("bad");

   int extracted_int = boost::python::extract<int>(t[0]);
   std::string extracted_string = boost::python::extract<std::string>(t[1]);
}
```

Comment: @Ramy You may wish to write a separate answer containing the elaboration.