# Boost Python: Error when passing variable by reference in a function

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I would like to understand why the following function does not work in python:

```
#include<boost/python.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void hello(std::string& s) {

   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
   boost::python::def("hello", hello);
}
```

When I import library into python

```
import test
test.hello('John')
```

I get an error:

```
test.hello(str)
did not match C++ signature:
   hello(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > {lvalue})
```

Everything works with just 'std::string s', but I would like to the object by reference without copying it. I noticed that the error pops up for any other function with references like e.g. int&.

Comment: If one way works, and the other way gives you an error message, that *usually* means you're supposed to do things the first way.

Comment: The string is coming from Python. If you got a reference to it, you could modify it. But strings are immutable in Python. So you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) mentioned, python strings are immutable. one solution can be a stl::string wrapper. your python side will be affected, but it's a simple solution and a small price to pay for that interface

```
class_<std::string>("StlString")
        .def(init<std::string>())
        .def_readonly("data", &std::string::data);
```

note that the *assign* operator, python to c++ stl will be given by boost, but you'll have to expose the *data* member in order to access the stored data. Iv'e added another costructor for the look and feel of c++ object.

```
>>> import test
>>> stlstr = test.StlString()
>>> stlstr
<test.StlString object at 0x7f1f0cda74c8>
>>> stlstr.data
''
>>> stlstr = 'John'
>>> stlstr.data
'John'
>>> initstr = test.StlString('John')
>>> initstr.data
'John'
```